# Does any open, simply extendible web crawler exists?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, nutch

I search for a web crawler solution which can is mature enough and can be simply extended. I am interested in the following features... or possibility to extend the crawler to meet them:

- partly just to read the feeds of several sites
- to scrape the content of these sites
- if the site has an archive I would like to crawl and index it as well
- the crawler should be capable to explore part of the Web for me and it should be able to decide which sites matches the given criteria
- should be able to notify me, if things possibly matching my interest were found
- the crawler should not kill the servers by attacking it by too many requests, it should be smart doing crawling
- the crawler should be robust against freak sites and servers

Those things above can be done one by one without any big effort, but I am interested in any solution which provide a customisable, extendible crawler. I heard of Apache Nutch, but very unsure about the project so far. Do you have experiences with it? Can you recommend alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search on [GitHub](http://github.com/) threw up [Anemone](http://github.com/chriskite/anemone), a web spider framework which seems to fit your requirements - particularly extensiblility. Written in Ruby.
Hope it goes well!

Comment: seems to be a good stuff, I like that it is ruby, which i like, the author created a nice dsl for crawlers. but compared to nutch still I don't see rss feed support and things like pdf crawling. but it is extendible. thanks for sharing the reference to anemone.

Answer (score 4):

I've used Nutch extensively, when I was building the open source project index for my Krugle startup. It's hard to customize, being a fairly monolithic design. There is a plug-in architecture, but the interaction between plug-ins and the system is tricky and fragile.

As a result of that experience, and needing something with more flexibility, I started the Bixo project - a web mining toolkit. http://openbixo.org.

Whether it's right for you depends on the weighting of factors such as:

1. How much flexibility you need (+)
2. How mature it should be (-)
3. Whether you need the ability to scale (+)
4. If you're comfortable with Java/Hadoop (+)

Answer (score 2):

I heartily recommend [heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org). It is VERY flexible and I'd argue is the most battle tested freely available open source crawler, as it's the one the Internet Archive uses.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find something that fits your needs [here](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-web-crawlers-java).

Comment: are these things only created in java?

Comment: The article is titled, "Open Source Web Crawlers Written in Java". However, you can find web crawlers built in other languages that may provide you with what you need.